# Android: Using getMaxAmplitude() from MediaRecorder while using PercussionOnsetDetector from TarsosDSP

Tags: java, android, audio, mediarecorder, tarsosdsp

I am trying to get the amplitude reading from every clap it detects but every time it detects a clap, I kept getting either an `IllegalStateException` or `0` from the `getMaxAmplitude()`.  Am I doing anything wrong? Is there a way around this? Please let me know!

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Checks Permission
    checkPermission(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION);

    double threshold = 8;
    double sensitivity = 45;

    PercussionOnsetDetector mPercussionDetector = new PercussionOnsetDetector(22050, 1024,
            new OnsetHandler() {

                @Override
                public void handleOnset(double time, double salience) {
                   /* try {
                        new MediaRecorder().setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                        new MediaRecorder().setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                        new MediaRecorder().setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                        new MediaRecorder().setOutputFile("dev/null");
                        new MediaRecorder().prepare();
                        new MediaRecorder().start();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } */

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            System.out.println(new MediaRecorder().getMaxAmplitude());
                            System.out.println("YAAAYYY");
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, sensitivity, threshold);

    dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(mPercussionDetector);
    new Thread(dispatcher,"Audio Dispatcher").start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [javadoc for MediaRecorder#getMaxAmplitude method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#getMaxAmplitude())
It says setAudioSource method should be invoked before.
Please pay attention to state and usage example in the beginning of this javadoc. getMaxAmplitude is just a getter, it doesn't perform actual recording.